# Do I need to use epoxy primer on fiberglass/epoxy before painting?

Tags: paint, epoxy

I am building a stitch&glue plywood boat that is coated with fiberglass and epoxy on the outside. I am trying to determine whenever I need to add epoxy primer on top of the epoxy coat before painting. The dealer who I bought the epoxy from says that it is not needed, as the resin he sold will act as a primer itself. I called another store, specializing in paints, and they say that I do need to buy epoxy primer from them to get a good grip for the paint.

I will be using two coats of polyurethane paint.

Can someone clear this up? Is there any practical difference between epoxy resin and epoxy primer? Do I really need to spend extra money on the expensive primer, when I still have lot of resin?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In terms of what is ideal I think this may depend on the exact nature of the epoxy and the paint rather that there being a single rule of thumb you can follow. However most paints will stick to nearly any substrate if a texture is provided for it to cling to (called mechanical bond). So if the surface of the epoxy/fibreglass coating is uniformly sanded and degreased there's a very good chance you'll get a good bond, it may not be the strongest bond possible. [contd]

Comment: If you want to skip using the epoxy primer it would be advisable to do an adhesion test, see final bullet point of [this Answer](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/3843/identifying-paint-type-on-finished-furniture/3852#3852).